# Restore content of UITableView when ViewController is popped [iOS][Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Currently, I have a ViewController with a UITableView that I use to display some content and I want to reuse for other views.  Currently, when a button is pressed, I'm using

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let destinationViewController: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
```

This creates an instance of the same ViewController and pushes it onto the stack while populating the UITableView with new content.

The problem that I have is that when I navigate back to the previous ViewController using the back button navigation item, the content in the previous ViewController's tableView is overwritten by the content of the ViewController's tableView that was pushed.

So, how do I reload the previous ViewController's tableView with its corresponding data from before it was pushed?

Comment: How is your data stored?  You need to make sure that the data source for the tableview reflects the information you want to display in the table

Comment: The data is stored as an NSArray

Comment: Ok, but you need to show more code.  What are you doing to the array in the second view controller?  If you have modified the array why would you expect the other view controller to show the old data?

Comment: Ahh ok I see what you're saying. I'll try a thing first.